# Let $T:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C} $ given by $ T(z)=(1+i)z$. Is $T$ injective or surjective?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $T:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C} $ given by $ T(z)=(1+i)z$. Is $T$ injective or surjective?

---

**Injection**

Let $m=(a+bi), n=(c+di)$ and suppose $f(m)=f(n)$ , then:

$\left\{\begin{aligned} 
      f(m) &= (1+i)(a+bi) \\ 
     f(n) &= (1+i)(c+di)
    \end{aligned}\right. \Rightarrow
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
     f(m) &= a-b+(a+b)i\\ \
     f(n) &= c-d+(c+d)i
    \end{aligned}\right.
\Rightarrow $

$\Rightarrow a-b+(a+b)i=c-d+(c+d)i$, then

$1) \left\{\begin{aligned} 
      a -b&= c-d \\ 
     a+b &= c+d
    \end{aligned}\right. \Rightarrow
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
     b &= a+d-c\\ \
     a+b &= c+d
    \end{aligned}\right.
\Rightarrow
a+a+d-c=c+d\Rightarrow a=c. $

$ 2) \left\{\begin{aligned} 
      a -b&= c-d \\ 
     a+b &= c+d
    \end{aligned}\right. \Rightarrow
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
     a &= b+c-d\\ \
     a+b &= c+d
    \end{aligned}\right.
\Rightarrow
b+c-d+b=c+d\Rightarrow b=d.$

So $(a,b)=(c,d) \rightarrow $ $T$ **is injective**

**Surjection**

Let $T(z)=y \in \mathbb{C}\rightarrow (1+i)z=y \rightarrow z=\frac{y}{1+i}$

$T\left (\frac{y}{1+i}\right )=(1+i)\frac{y}{(1+i)}=y\in \mathbb{C}$

So  $T$ is surjective

---

**Is correct my answer?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, you could also note that $T \ne 0$ is linear and therefore it is bijective.

Comment: Just  to be shure and not creat an inncesary new question , is $T ^{-1} (1-i)=(1-i)^2/2$

Comment: $T^{-1}(z)= {1\over 1+i}z = (1-i)z/2$, so the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha$ be just any non-zero complex number.

Then the map $T_\alpha(z)=\alpha z$ has an inverse, namely $(T_\alpha)^{-1}=T_{\alpha^{-1}}$, and thus must be a bijection (both injective and surjective).

Note that this is a purely set-theoretic argument: it doesn't use that the map $T_\alpha$ is linear.